# Строковое преобразование

Tags: javascript

```
alert("string" === "string"); //true
alert("string" === "true"); //false
```

Аналогично

```
alert(String(false) === "false"); //true
alert(String(false) === "string");  //false
```

Обьясните, почему во второй строке выводит false, ведь сравниваются типы данных, или то, что там написано тоже влияет?

Comment: сравниваются типы данных **и** значения

Comment: Сравниваются значения и типы данных. Если нужно сравнить тип данных, для этого есть метод typeof.

Comment: вы пытаетесь в первом случае сравнить значение строки `"string"` со значением строки `"true"`

Во втором случае аналогично